# Select parent xml tag

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I select parent tag?

Following is the XPath and it works fine, but select the "**str**" node where filter is applied.

```
/response/lst[@name='grouped']/lst[@name='city']/arr[@name='groups']/lst/str[@name='groupValue'][text()='Boston']
```

So after applying the filter i want to return the **lst** node one right above the final str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is to just place the `str...` part in a predicate (square brackets):

```
/response/lst[@name='grouped']/lst[@name='city']/arr[@name='groups']/lst[str[@name='groupValue'][text()='Boston']]
```

note the `[...]` around `str...`.  that way your expression ends at `lst`, which is what you want.